# symfony2 capifony deploy in dev environment

Tags: php, symfony, deployment, capistrano, capifony

Despite all my attemps, I am unable to deploy my symfony2 application with capifony in dev environment.

I have tried the following in my .rb file:

```
set :clear_controllers, false
```

This allows me to not delete the app_dev.php and yes, that way I can access the dev environment but only by manually putting this file in the address bar

These other parameters have no effect on wether the app_dev.php is used by default :

```
set :composer_options,  "--dev --verbose --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader --no-progress"
set :symfony_env,  "dev"
```

And in my apache2 conf file, I have put this

```
DirectoryIndex app_dev.php
```

What other hidden parameter to I need to use in order for the page to automatically display the dev environment when accessing the root directory ?

Comment: The key bit is a) having the file there (`:clear_controllers`) and b) having Apache serve that file by default (`DirectoryIndex`).  I have a similar `DirectoryIndex app.php` setting in a default Symfony `.htaccess` file in the root of my web dir (and it works) - is it possible you have the same, and it's overriding your conf settings?

Comment: yes, I've got this in my .htaccess ! I'll try this the next time I update but it should finally do it :) thanks !

Comment: Make sure that rewrite rules also point to your app_dev.php